# Vue3 setup how to define channels?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm not very familiar with VUE, And Now I'm learning vue3, but I got some problem

- **vue2 define channels like this:**

```js
<script>
  export default {
    channels: {
    NoticesChannel: {
      connected () {
        console.log('connected')
      },
      received (data) {
        console.log("data", data);
      },
      rejected() {
      console.log("rejected");
    },
    received(data) {
      console.log("data", data);
    },
    disconnected() {
      console.log("disconnected");
    },
    }
  }
  }
</script>
```

- How can I set channels method take effect with vue3 setup?

```js
<script setup>
// how to define channels
</script>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: From where do you get the channels API?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim It's customized

Comment: How is it customized? could you provide a link where this is explained

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I'm use `actioncable-vue` plug-in，Maybe in there define ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/actioncable-vue

Comment: It looks like this plugin doesn't provide any composable stuff to work with composition API (setup syntax)

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Ok, thank you, maybe I have to use `export default`.

Comment: You're welcome, Keep using the options api